# How Can I Have A Random Image Selected From A Set List of Images?

Tags: objective-c

Hi and thanks for helping. I simply just want to randomize what image shows up so that there is a different one displaying every time. Here is my code, and the images I want to add to get randomized are for instance "tutorial2.png" and "tutorial3.png"

```
self.help=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"tutorial.png"];
    self.help.position=ccp(ws.width/2,ws.height*4/4/2);
    [self addChild:self.help];
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could get the index of an array of image using...

```
int r = arc4random() % /*Number of images here*/;
```

Comment: Hey sorry but i have no clue as to what that is or where to put it, could you posiiby show how this could be added to my actual code that i have? thanks